# Deploy Google App Script as API Executable logged in as Editor

Tags: google-apps-script

I've noticed that only the Owner of a Google App Script is able to Publish > Deploy as API Executable the App Script. When any other users that has been added as an Editor tries to do the same, they get an error `Failed to retrieve script's execution endpoint information.`

Is there a way to allow other team members with editor rights to the App Script perform the Publish > Deploy as API Executable?

Answer (score 3):

Please try setting `devmode:false`.

As mentioned in [Using the Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api), if `devmode` is true, only the owner of the script can execute in development mode.

You may also refer to this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920443/why-does-my-apps-script-deployed-as-api-executable-return-permission-denied) for additional information on why you encountered the error.