# Google API Executable permission denied error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I have a small Google Apps Script that I have deployed as API executable.
Although I have made the call with a valid token for the scope I'm using (spreadsheets), I can't get past this `403 PERMISSION_DENIED` error.
I'm now testing this on the [API's Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/) with the same error.

Does anyone have any ideas of what I might be missing?

My script is simple (still incomplete, but it runs - which should be enough for these initial tests):

```
OAuth Scope required by script (copied from API's Explorer):
https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets

function myFunction(get) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1axDlnPaoEwhlb_Vs5SLBvkGJrR-fSeOLuHEdSBXCTBg"); // I'm not getting anything from the sheet at this point, I included it just to make sure that the script requires the spreadsheets scope

  get += " " + "success!";

  return  ContentService.createTextOutput(get);
}
```

The request (copied from API's Explorer):

```
POST https://script.googleapis.com/v1/scripts/1d1EKj7vi-gzC0gB02qjw_qBPE1zSrZtJp-YUWuKm3NL3-3t6Sixpm0TZ:run?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

{
 "function": "myFunction",
 "parameters": [
 "Hello world!"
 ]
}
```

The response (copied from API's Explorer):

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "The caller does not have permission",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to check these 3 things:

- Make sure that your app script is associated with the correct Dev Console Project.
- Enable Apps Script Execution API.
- If you're running a function in an Apps Script using `Method: scripts.run`, set `devMode: true` if you're the owner of the script. Otherwise, use the default value which is `false`.

Also, you should meet the listed requirements in [Using the Execution API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api).

See this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32920443/why-does-my-apps-script-deployed-as-api-executable-return-permission-denied/37189310) for additional insights.

Comment: The issue was the first point: my script was associated with the wrong console project.

Answer (score 1):

The script should be associated with the developer console project id that corresponds with OAuth 2.0 client ID used (On the script editor of your current script: `Resources > Cloud Platform Project`, then enter your project id number)
This was the reason why **my** script wasn't working (yours may differ, see [Teyam's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44094740/961546) answer which I've marked as the correct one).