# Status code 403 opening a drive's image with google apps script

Tags: html, google-apps-script, http-status-code-403

I'm working to an image gallery, the image's names and id are in a google spreadsheet, the script read the spreadsheet and dynamically publish the images. At the begin it worked fine, now i have a status code 403.

To debug the problem I have hardcoded a single image in a very simple test script

This is "Code.gs"

```
function doGet(request) {
  var htmlTemplate=HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("prova");
  return htmlTemplate.evaluate();
}
```

This is "prova.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   <img src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=11CakSm75WDYnpfd_Qs2LlYoVmJwdAmUR" alt="sample" />
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the header from the error:

```
Stato:              403
Versione:           HTTP/2
Trasferito:         1,39 kB (dim. 0 B)
Referrer Policy:    strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Priorità richiesta: Low
Risoluzione DNS:    Sistema
```

[This is the link at the debug script](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxm79g7tpiBzbnbudIOc8UiXutwCcnw2sJ_-rpj6f4Pje9Kk-97Spp8Z1FKT-Pr3z-WrA/exec)

The script reply with code 403, but the direct [link to the image](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=11CakSm75WDYnpfd_Qs2LlYoVmJwdAmUR) works fine!

I can't understand how to resolve the problem.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Is your situation related to this thread? https://stackoverflow.com/q/77829172

Comment: Can you please elaborate your concern, when you say dynamically publish the images is this your own webpage/website? when did you start encountering the error? also have you seen this thread: [Error 403 when I open an image link in Google SpreadSheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65917210/error-403-when-i-open-an-image-link-in-google-spreadsheet) and [Error 403 on Google Sheets API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42806893/error-403-on-google-sheets-api)

Comment: @Tanaike don't think it's related

Comment: @Twilight Thanks for help. The production script generates the image's URLs reading the information from a spreadsheet and uses javascript to manage the page (position, filters, etc.). To exclude possible errors I have simplified the code to a minimum. The direct link to the image works, the same link from the script gives an error. Of course i have seen the suggested thread.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `@Tanaike don't think it's related`, I understood your reply. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the correct syntax for the link. Not by my own, but in the Philippe reply to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70798664/google-drive-image-gives-403-forbidden-error/70895934#70895934), who had the hint from this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70143719/717372).
The trick is:

```
> https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/d/[image id]
```

instead of

```
> https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=[image id]
```

Hope it can help.